# props variable undefined in react

Tags: react-native

I am new to react and trying to access json data from a file using props.

Header.js

```
import React from 'react';
export const Header = props => (
<div className="curator-info col-lg-8 col-md-8 padLeft">
   <p><span id="curator-info-tagline">List Curated by:</span><br/>
   <span id="curator-info-name">{props.user_first_name} {props.user_middle_name} {props.user_surname}
   </span></p>
</div>      
);
export default Header;
```

restraunts.js

```
const restraunts = [
{  
    id:12,
    user_first_name:'Illias',
    user_middle_name:'',
    user_surname:'Dcruze',
},
];
export default restraunts;
```

Layout.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../Header/Header';
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer';
import restraunts from '../../data/restraunts.js';

export const Layout = props => (
<div className="app-container">
<Header />
<Footer />
</div>
);

export default Layout;
```

Somewhere i read to get data in componentmount functions but i guess it is only possible if i create a class using react.component

Tried this along with other options:

```
In header.js
export const Header = ({restraunts}) => (

In Layout.js
< Header restraunts={restraunts} />
```

Queries:
1) Here props.user_first_name should be printed but i am getting undefined in front end(not undefined error but span tag is empty).

Edit 1: As suggested in the answer, i should loop. i found i should pass props as parameter too when it is called in Layout.js file

Comment: hey can you just line up the queries at the end of the question so that i can write illustrative answer.

Comment: @Codesingh both queries numbered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop through the `restraunts` array to show each one and its values.

`Header.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
export const Header = props => (
<div className="curator-info col-lg-8 col-md-8 padLeft">
   <p><span id="curator-info-tagline">List Curated by:</span><br/>
   {props.restraunts.map((restaurant, index) => 
       <span key={index} id="curator-info-name">{restaurant.user_first_name} {restaurant.user_middle_name} {restaurant.user_surname}
       </span>
   )}</p>
</div>      
);
export default Header;
```

Comment: tried props.restraunts with Header = props, Header= restraunts (in this props undefined is error), then tried Header= restraunts and restraaunts .user_first_name...  nothing works @pat-needham

Comment: One thing I just noticed is that in your `restraunt.js` file, you're exporting an array of objects, not the object itself. The spear operator won't be good with that, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: just edited file name restraunt.js is restraunts.js though it doesnt matter i guess

Comment: giving error unexpected token, at }</p> . tried adding , and ;

Comment: Try with the closing parentheses

Comment: thank you, it worked, should i be using this syntax for loading say 30 values from restraunts.js
I am planning to make a view of different restraunts. so will this be apropriate ?

Comment: For that, one option is to make a `Restaurant` component, then within the `.map((restaurant, index) => ` you can replace the `span` tag with `<Restaurant key={index} {...restaurant} />` as that would be a more appropriate use of the spread operator I initially suggested.